# How to design a common class to accept a list and dbset

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity

I have some business logic that is used by both an api and a job manager which uses a database to store data.  simplified like this:.

```
class BusinessLogic 
{
    public IEnumerable<Request> Requests {get;set;}

    public List<Requests> GetData()
    {
         return Requests.Where(r => r.StatusId == Constants.STATUS_NOT_PROCESSED_ID).ToList();
    }
}

class apiprocessor
{
    public void Process()
    {
        var requests = new List<Request>();

        BusinessLogic.Requests = requests;
        BusinessLogic.GetData();
    }
}

class dbprocessor
{
    private DbContext _db;

    public void Process()
    {
        //this sends the where clause to the db
        //var requests = _db.Requests.Where(r => r.StatusId == Constants.STATUS_NOT_PROCESSED_ID).ToList();

        BusinessLogic.Requests = _db.Requests;  //type DbSet<Request> Requests
        //this one doesnt
        BusinessLogic.GetData();
    }
}
```

functionally this works but there is a problem.

if i try and get the data using the dbcontext in the db processor the resulting query that the mysql server receives is:

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`RequestID`, 
`Extent1`.`RequestType`, 
`Extent1`.`StatusId`
FROM `Requests` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE (0 = `Extent1`.`StatusId`)
```

(notice the WHERE clause)

when the same code is run in the BusinessLogic class above, the resulting query is:

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`RequestID`, 
`Extent1`.`RequestType`, 
`Extent1`.`StatusId`
FROM `Requests` AS `Extent1`
```

the Where clause is missing which means that the entire table is being retrieved and then the where clause is being applied to the data in memory

is there anyway to design the common class so that when it gets called with a dbset it sends the where clause to the db?

EDIT: To be clear, IQueryable is not an option because List does not inherit from it which is what the api processor uses.  However, using a List in the api processor is not mandatory

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
IQuerable<Request> Requests
```

instead of

```
IEnumerable<Request> Requests
```

Update:
You can use a repository pattern. I use [this](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/documentation) pattern which is very lightweight and extendable.

Comment: already tried this, List<T> doesnt inherit from IQueryable.  unless you can suggest something to use besides List

Comment: You can use IQueryable<Request> i = _db.Request.AsQueryable(); to get querable object.

Comment: DbContext implements both interfaces, but apparently the two Where implementations (of each interface) are not calling the same code. Rather than swapping List<T> for something more complicated just so you can match IQueryable Linq behavior, I suggest separating how data is loaded versus how its filtered. Why not just call `BusinessLogic.Requests = _db.Requests.Where(r => r.StatusId == Constants.STATUS_NOT_PROCESSED_ID).ToList()`? It appears that apiprocessor has alternative ways of getting the list of entities, so you still want to filter on that list? Why not also pre-filter it separately?

Comment: @CPerkins hmm the pre-filtering sounds like an interesting idea.  ill try that out as i wait for more answers

Answer (score 0):

You could use `IQuerable<Request>` instead of `IEnumerable<Request>`.

However, it is not common to have a separate `BusinessLogic` class just to maintain `IQuerable<Request>`.

Those whoever needs the data could have called straight to `_db.Requests`.

```
var result = _db.Requests
   .Where(r => r.StatusId == Constants.STATUS_NOT_PROCESSED_ID)
   .ToList()
```

Or, you could just create a repository layer like [this](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit/blob/master/src/Libraries/Asp.Repositories/Users/UserRepository.cs) to keep all logic.

If you do not like neither of above approach, you can use ***[Specification pattern](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/02/08/specification-pattern-c-implementation/)***.

Comment: edited the main post since you are the second person to mention IQueryable.  IQueryable is not an option because List does not inherit from it which is what the api processor uses. However, using a List in the api processor is not mandatory

Comment: `DbSet` has AsQueryable extension method. You can use as `_db.Requests.AsQueryable()`. By the way, are you trying to implement ***Repository Pattern***?